# "app not installed" when installing signed apk

Tags: android

I recently forked a project and created a signed apk, I already changed the package name both in gradle file and manifest, and also signed the apk with signature version V1 and V2, but upon installing it says "app not installed".
The original app was installed in my device, but after uninstalling it the signed apk I created starts installing. Any idea what caused this to happen?

Comment: Try installing it with `adb install`. You'll get a detailed error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android treats apps as different kernel-level user, they must have a unique user ID and group ID.

My guess is that you didn't fully change it by rename those strings, try these steps and see if it can help you :

- uncheck `Compact Empty Middle Packages` options
- use `rename package` function of Android studio

For more details: [Android Studio Rename Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package)

And sometimes same app with different key (debug / release key) will cause the same problems.